# mysql need to get custom order of result

Tags: mysql

Have MySQL table like `id`, `parent_id`, `order_nr`

Now selecting everything like this

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

And getting result like

```
`id`, `parent_id`, `order_nr`
"27",   "23",       "3" 
"26",   "23",       "2" 
"25",   "23",       "1" 
"24",   "0",        "0" 
"23",   "0",        "0" 
"22",   "0",        "0"
```

Need to get same result just in order like this:

```
`id`, `parent_id`, `order_nr`
"24",   "0",        "0" 
"23",   "0",        "0" 
"25",   "23",       "3" 
"26",   "23",       "2" 
"27",   "23",       "1"
"22",   "0",        "0"
```

Comment: In natural language, please explain how to order the first set to get the second set (the third set is obvious). Thanks in advance.

Comment: edited my quesction exxamples.. I need what all ID's would be from MAX to MIN, also add in the order of example ID 23 wheres parent_id 23 order of order_nr,

Answer (score 2):

how about this one:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE 1 ORDER BY order_nr,parent_id,id DESC
```

you can try to swap what column should be order first.

Comment: that's what i needed! Thanks ! :)

Comment: actually i find out that I need someting more not only like this.. :) 

edited my quesction examples

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `parent_id` and `order_nr` are varchar columns, but you want to sort them as numbers, then you can cast the columns when you order:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
ORDER BY CAST(parent_id AS SIGNED),   -- no need for CAST if already numeric
         CAST(order_nr AS SIGNED)
```

Note: Your first desired output does not seem to have any evident logic behind, so I gave a solution for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `parent_id`, `order_nr` ASC
```

Output would be like:

```
`id`, `parent_id`, `order_nr`
"24",   "0",        "0" 
"23",   "0",        "0" 
"22",   "0",        "0" 
"25",   "22",       "1" 
"26",   "22",       "2" 
"27",   "22",       "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming two digits numbers for ids (but can be extended to any number of digits)

```
SELECT IF(parent_id=0,id,parent_id)*100+IF(parent_id=0,0,id)),* FROM table ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

or if ids are strings

```
SELECT CONCAT(IF(parent_id='0',LPAD(id,2,'0'),LPAD(parent_id,2,'0')),IF(parent_id='0','00',LPAD(id,2,'0'))),* FROM table ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

This will give you a first column which is

2400
2300
2227
2226
2225
2200

Answer (score 0):

When the `parent_id` is 0 then just use the `id` otherwise use the `parent_id`; sorting by `order_nr` then breaks ties. All sorting is descending order:

```
SELECT id, parent_id, order_nr,
       id AS sort_order
  FROM table1
 WHERE parent_id = '0'
UNION
SELECT id, parent_id, order_nr,
       parent_id AS sort_order
  FROM table1
 WHERE parent_id <> '0'
 ORDER
    BY sort_order DESC, order_nr DESC;
```